# Unable to select id of appended div with 'ends with' selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Through my work, I've determined how to successfully select an appended div on click:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deletebutton', function() {
```

I've also successfully selected divs using the 'ends with' jquery selector

```
$(document).on('click', '[id$=button]', function() {
```

When I attempt to select an appended div WITH the 'ends with' jquery selector, this doesn't work. Any thoughts on why this might be?

Thanks!

Comment: `.deletebutton` is a class, not an ID, so an ID that ends with "button" will not match the element with class "deletebutton".

Comment: What does your DOM structure look like? If you had `id="somebutton"`, that selector would work. It is a successful example of the ends with selector. (You *could* do it with `class` instead of `id`, but it would only match `class="something deletebutton"` but **not** `class="deletebutton something"` because it's not at the end.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder You were right thanks for correcting.

Comment: @MaheerAli - No worries. *(Not my downvote, either. :-) )*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. There was a syntax error in my code. I apologize. It should be:

$(document).on('click', '[class$=button]', function() {

Comment: This selector is not guaranteed to work. If you have `<div class="somebutton">` then yes it works, also if you have `<div class="something somebutton">` but not if you have `<div class="somebutton something">`. This is because the string ""somebutton something"" does not end with "button". You should probably rethink your approach here - one option is to have a common class like "button" on everything, another to use a comma to list all the classes that end with "button" - e.g., `$(document).on('click', '.deletebutton,.addbutton,.editbutton', function() {`